# AngularJS - Put $http interceptor in separate file

Tags: angularjs, http, angular-http-interceptors

How can I put my interceptor in a separate file and push it in the $httpProvider within the configuration block.

Here's my configuration block at the moment:

```
(function() {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('app')
    .config(config);

  config.$inject = ['$httpProvider'];

  function config($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.defaults.withCredentials = true;
    $httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push(['$injector', '$q', function($injector, $q) {
      return {
        responseError: function(response) {
          var toastr = $injector.get('toastr');
          var lodash = $injector.get('lodash');
          toastr.error(lodash.get(response, 'data.message', 'Alguma coisa deu errado.'));
          if (response.status !== 401) {
            return $q.reject(response);
          }

          var userService = $injector.get('userService');
          if (userService.isLogged()) {
            userService.logout();
          }

          var $state = $injector.get('$state');
          $state.go('login');
          return $q.reject(response);
        }
      };
    }]);
  }
})();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a factory using your code inside `return {.....}` and push that factory to intercepters collection.

`angular
    .module('app')
    .config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {

    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('yourInterceptorFactoryName');
}]);`

Comment: Thanks! I I created a separate factory and pushed it. Worked!!